# react native map is not updating custom style directly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I have created a custom map style using react native maps but sometimes it shows a default map for 1-2 seconds then a new style will update. Is there any way we can check the map is loaded or not?

```
<MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        customMapStyle={customMapStyle}
        showsCompass={false}
        showsScale={false}
        showsBuildings={false}
        showsTraffic={false}
        showsIndoors={false}
        showsUserLocation={false}
        zoomEnabled={true}
        pitchEnabled={true}
        zoomTapEnabled={true}
        {...props}
        style={[styles.map, mapStyle as any]}
    >
        {props.children}
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to use `onMapReady` event.

[DOC](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#events)

It will "Callback that is called once the map is fully loaded."

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help me . This callback is called when map is loaded.  Not custom map style.